# Determine different seeds for which random shuffling list generates the same output

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

It is pretty intuitive that when shuffling a small enough collection, results will repeat themselves, even using different seeds each time, as it is just a matter of exhausting all unique combinations.

However, I can't find such information in the Python documentation. I am especially curious if there is any formula or algorithm to determine the different seed values for which the output would be identical. Is it possible to somehow forecast or calculate these seeds?

At first sight, I couldn't see any pattern or regular offset, and now it intrigues me if it's possible to find one

I'm pasting the snippet of the code that I reproduced several times on my machine and within the online REPL.

```py
import random

a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
b = list(a)
c = list(a)

random.seed(0)
random.shuffle(a)
random.seed(344)
random.shuffle(b)
random.seed(496)
random.shuffle(c)

print(a == b == c == ["c", "b", "a", "e", "d"])  # True
```

Comment: Interestingly, using strings (eg. `random.seed("496")`) as a seed produces correct (random) results across the 3 lists.

Comment: I guess it's because seeds of other types are converted to int, IIUC the documentation: `With version 2 (the default), a str, bytes, or bytearray object gets converted to an int and all of its bits are used.` https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed

Comment: Yes, if you initialize with large numbers (e.g. `1000`, `100344`, `100496`) then you'll get random lists.

Comment: Still, intriguing if there is a smarter way to get those seeds, other than naive brute force :)

Comment: You will probably need something like this: https://github.com/eboda/mersenne-twister-recover or https://github.com/fx5/not_random Here is discussion on SO: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/80979/how-many-12-bit-integers-output-are-required-to-reverse-the-mersenne-twister

Comment: Note that you're implicitly conditioning on at least three algorithms here: the random number generator (i.e. MT19937), how your seed is transformed into the state used by the RNG, and how the shuffle implemention uses random values to modify the list.  You might also include the algorithm for turning draws from the RNG into values in `0 <= x < n`.  Each of these choices determine which seeds produce the same permutation and would be an integral part of any analysis.

Comment: Thanks @SamMason for pointing that out, I had a feeling that this issue is more complicated and indeed, as it is the result of the cooperation of several different algorithms, now I see the complexity here ;)